# Add link to PDF within a PDF file using relative addressing

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I want to add a link to some  text within a PDF that will bring up another PDF that is located in the same folder. I wish to use relative addressing so that the PDF suite is transportable to other users and computers. I wish this to work on Linux and Macs.
LibreOffice Draw, despite promises, writes out the link address as a full path. Thus if taken to another computer with another user the link fails to work.
I tried manually editing the PDF files using vi and altered the link syntax so;

```
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/Rect[940.9 480.3 1200.7 507.9]/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(Content/Information.pdf)>>
```

where the target file, "Information.pdf" is in a subdirectory "Contents".

On Linux using Document Viewer, it works! On an Apple, Preview (a PDF viewer) interprets the target file needs to be opened by some application. Adobe Reader doesn't like this syntax either. I tried prefixing the filename with the keyword "file:" which works for a full path but not with relative addressing.
Does anyone know what syntax might work for me

Comment: I tried KJ's syntax suggestions but nothing worked. I was passed a few PDFs from and old printer help file. Buttons on one of the PDF linked to another PDF in the same folder. Sadly the files are in some binary format and the referenced filenames are not visible. Nevertheless it shows that it can be done. The PDF reference manual doesn't contain local relative addressing information but does mention linking to internal pages. There are Python programs that add links to a PDF. Forums suggest they are buggy. I may have to explore this approach.

Comment: The printing PDF example that references local files was compressed. I used Python

Comment: The PDF Example file was compressed and can be uncompressed with Python, so import pypdftk; pypdftk.uncompress("myinfile.pdf","myoutfile.pdf") The file can then be read with a text editor such as vi. This example created objects that were then called by other object. There were dictionaries a containing Rect information and most importantly the keyword Action and Launch keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a PDF you can select text and add a hyperlink using LibreOffice Draw. It is then possible to edit the PDF file with a text editor such as vi.
To find the line with the link search for the filename of the target. One problem is that LibreOffice insists in using a fully qualified domain name to locate the file and this won't work after the file is moved, say to another computer. The unedited line should be similar to;

```
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/Rect[940.9 480.3 1200.7 507.9]/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(File:<fullpathname>/Content/Information.pdf)>>
```

Where Content/Information.pdf is the link target in the same directory as the linking pdf. This line should be changed to

```
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/Rect[940.9 480.3 1200.7 507.9]/A<</Type/Action/S /Launch/F(Content/Information.pdf)>>
```

This works on Unix and MacOs